# How to capture a rectangle within the Quantum GIS software?

Tags: qgis, digitizing, map-drawing

I want to use "capture polygon" function in QGIS software to draw the indoor office cubical which is a rectangle shape. But the "capture polygon" function is not able to draw a perfect rectangle shape. How to draw a rectangle feature in Qgis software when you are creating a feature?

Answer (score 6):

You can chose between [**CAD Tools** plugin](http://www.catais.org/qgis/cadtools/) which is more complex and more powerful,

or [**Rectangles ovals digitizing** plugin](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/easy-rectangles-circles-and-ellipses-in-qgis/).

[image]

After installing the plugin you may have trouble to locate the plugin tool icon or buttons. Look for the plugin tool icons in the toolbars, they are probably in grey color.

[image]

Comment: I have installed the "Rectangles ovals digitizing" plugin but I am not able to see the nice tool bar on my QGIS software interface. All I get is some message says: "This plugin is working properly if your input point layer is projected in coordinate system with Northings and Eastings are measured in metres and your width and height value are set in metres". I don't quite understand it. I guess I have to setup some parameters when I add the "raster layser" in order to use this nice plugin?

Comment: It is saying you need to use a UTM projection. Set this in project properties/settings CRS. Also the same setting is accessible from the bottom right of the screen. To find a suitable projection for your territory, google EPSG. You want to find what zone you are in for the second part of the sequence
WGS / UTM Zone 43N

Comment: I have found the plugin tool bar after a thorough checking on my QGis software panel. (there are too many icons) So it's right to follow the above instructions to download/install the plugins. Even though there are warning message but you can just ignore it and proceed to use the plugin without problem at all. I have amended the answer to include this discovery.